# How to add Default SEQ.nextval() to PK-Column in SQL datamodeler

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm dealing with one issue.
Using sql datamodeler I tried to add an autoincrementing primary key column.

In sql it looks like PK_ID NUMBER(10) default seq_pk_id.nextval().
But how can I tell sql datamodoler to do that?

There's an autoincrement option in the relational view but it just add the creation of the sequence to the DDL not the default option on the primary key column.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? Or to which version is Data Modeler set? Using a sequence as a default value requires 12.1 or newer

Answer (score 0):

you can use a trigger for this column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SET_PK_ID
  BEFORE INSERT ON Table_Name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT seq_pk_id.nextval
  INTO :new.PK_ID
  FROM dual;
END;
```